# Best algorithm to make our VM's Up and running

Tags: algorithm, virtual-machine

Suppose i have a data center and i provide VM'S as a service to my customer.For every VM i have 5 update VM set which we use it while we push some patches.
What algorithm i should use to keep my VM up and running while i am doing sytem upgrade. How to make sure VM won't go down due to some activity.